# How should I create a simple enough regex for multiple specified URLs with two different parent paths for Google Analytics?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

First ever question post - so apologies in advance.

I have created the Custom Report in Google Analytics

and I'm trying to create a list of matching slugs to two different parent folders to sit within the same custom report.

I can get this to work as a custom report:

/courses/(course-slug-1|course-slug-2)$

the problem is I can't add this set of regex to it as well without breaking the custom report;

/study/faculty/(key-page-1|key-page-2)$

How is the way i should bundle this regex to show these pages. For context there is 63 course page urls and 5 key pages I want in this same custom report to bring it to a total of 68.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Filters in custom reports get applied in series. The first filter limits the data, then second filter is applied to that already-filtered set, and so on.

You need to create the regex expression in a single filter:

```
/courses/(course-slug-1|course-slug-2)$|/study/faculty/(key-page-1|key-page-2)$
```

That should do it.

Comment: Thank you Michael yes this was the way i ended up doing it but thank you for reiterating.